# Array manipulation Placement Interview Question

Tags: arrays, algorithm

> There is an array arr of n positive integers which represents the
> amount of water (in liters) in the ith glass. By watering X liters of
> water to a tree with height H, the height of the tree will increase by
> X units only if amount of water is more than the height of tree
> otherwise tree will soak the water and its height will not increase.
> Your task is to help Harry to water the tree with initial height 0
> using n glasses of water in any order to maximize the height of the
> tree and return the maximum possible height of the tree. Note: One
> glass can be used only once, and you can't mix water of multiple
> glasses in one glass.
>
> Input Specification:
>
> - input1: An integer n representing the available number of water glasses.
> - input2: An integer array arr representing the amount of water in the ith glass. Output Specification: Return an integer value representing
>   the maximum possible height of the tree.
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> input1:3 
> input2: (2,1,2)
> Output: 3
> ```

I am fairly new to coding and could not solve it. My approach was to sort the array in ascending order and iterate from 0 index to last index. If current height < array element, add it to current height. Otherwise move to next element. The test case in the question was fulfilled.

However consider another test case. `arr=[1,4,5,7,9]`. According to my approach, `height= 1+4+7=12` will be returned. However, the following possibility exists: `height= 1+5+9=15`. So, my algorithm returns maximum possible height in select cases only.

Comment: Using `1+7+9` you can even achieve 17

Comment: @nokla OP *did* use a greedy algorithm, it was not optimal

Comment: @Bergi I meant to sort it in descending order and start from the biggest number, then go check what is the next number that could fit.

Comment: If you try it with the array in the example: `9 -> 7`; Then  `5` wouldn't work because `5+7 > 9` and same for `4` which gives you `1+7+9`

Comment: @nokla Actually that doesn't quite work either, for `[3,4,6,9]` it would choose `6+9` not `3+4+9`. But it's going in the right direction I think

Comment: I guess you'll need to basically try all possible combinations, I can't think of a straightforward linear solution. You can do it naively, but you can try optimising it a bit by employing [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Computer_science) or [branch-and-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound).

Comment: You might have forgotten to ask a question ...

Comment: @Bergi, considering that the glasses can be drained "...in any order..." I don't see how dynamic programming can be used.

Comment: @CarySwoveland "*can be*", but it only makes sense to use glasses in ascending order, the OP is on track with that part. Once you have sorted the input, the question is only which glasses to pick.

Comment: @Bergi, I initially thought using the glasses in ascending order might be optimal, and sought to prove that. However, it's easy to come up with a counterexample. Suppose the heights and order of the glasses were `[2,3,5]`. Then the final height of the tree will be `5`. If, however, the glasses are reordered to `[3,2,5]` the final height of the tree will be `8`, so ordering the glasses by size will not necessarily produce an optimal solution. Incidentally, note that the OP stated that all the glasses must be used, it only being a question of their order.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It is nowhere stated that all glasses must be used? In your example, the output should be `[3,5]` (an ascending list) - `2` will not grow the tree.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Or let me rephrase it: any minimal (no useless glasses chosen) and optimal (reaching max height) solution will have the chosen glasses in ascending order.

Comment: @Bergi, the OP said, "...array arr of n positive integers", then "Your task is to help Harry to water the tree with initial height 0 using n glasses of water in any order..." then "One glass can be used only once,...", which means that each glass must used exactly once (though some may not grow the tree). As the height is initially zero 2 in [2,3,5] will grow the tree to 2 (0+2, since 2 > 0), 3 will grow it to 5 (2+3, since 3 > 2) and 5 will grow it no more (as 5 <= 5).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah ok, I didn't spot that. Though actually it doesn't really matter. The output is not the list of glasses, it's the maximum reachable tree height. From a minimal solution, we can always get a solution that uses all glasses by simply appending the not chosen glasses.

Comment: @Bergi, I expect you are correct about appending the glasses not chosen, but I would still want proof. There is, however, a problem of a combinatorially-expanding size of the DP's state space. If, for example, the glasses were [1,4,5,6], after selecting or not glass #1 there would be two possible states of tree height: [0,1], after selecting or not the glass #2 there would be four possible states:  [0,1,4,5]; after selecting or not glass #3 there would be six possible states: [0,1,4,5,6,9] and after selecting or not glass #4 there would be nine possible states: [0,1,4,5,6,9,7,10,11]...

Comment: ... Although the size of the state space is not growing at 2^n, it's clear that, depending on n and the distribution of the contents of glasses a DP approach may not be computationally feasible.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The proof is straightforward: the optimal solution always includes the largest glass - by contradiction, we could reach a higher tree in any other solution by swapping out the last chosen glass for the largest. If the largest glass is always part of the solution, the height of the tree is as least that, and any other (smaller) glasses appended to the minimal solution will no longer be able to grow the tree. Re combinatorial explosion: I'd try to go backwards and cut the search tree, but I haven't completely figured it out, otherwise I would have posted an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can consider that this problem boils down to getting a subset of the integers in such a fashion that the height obtained by sum of previous waters given to the tree doesn't exceed the current one.

---

So, every integer is either a part of the solution or it isn't.

---

This problem represents one of our classic algorithms which is [`0-1 knapsack problem`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

- We first sort the integers to keep things simple and we only take distinct elements in the array since duplicate ones don't apply here as the height would get equal or more instantly.
- For every element, if the current sum is greater than itself, we pass it on to the next element, else, we try 2 ways - include the current element and move  to next elements or exclude the current element and move to the next one. We take maximum of both possibilities and update our answer.
- To avoid repeated subproblems, we cache the results in our array, say `dp`.

**Snippet(Python):**

```py
def knapsack(dp, currIdx, currSum, ls, size, ans):
    if currIdx == size: return 0
    if currSum in dp[currIdx]: return dp[currIdx][currSum]
    if currSum >= ls[currIdx]:
        dp[currIdx][currSum] =  knapsack(dp, currIdx + 1, currSum, ls, size, ans)
    else:
        dp[currIdx][currSum] = max(
            ls[currIdx] + knapsack(dp, currIdx + 1, currSum + ls[currIdx], ls, size, ans),
            knapsack(dp, currIdx + 1, currSum, ls, size, ans)
        )
    ans[0] = max(ans[0], dp[currIdx][currSum])
    return dp[currIdx][currSum]
    
def solve(ls):
    ls = list(set(ls))
    ls.sort()
    dp = []
    ans = [0]
    for i in range(len(ls)):
        dp.append(dict())
    knapsack(dp, 0, 0, ls, len(ls), ans)
    return ans[0]
    
print([1,4,5,7,9], solve([1,4,5,7,9]))
print([3,4,6,9], solve([3,4,6,9]))
print([2,1,2], solve([2,1,2]))
print([1,2,4,8,16], solve([1,2,4,8,16]))
print([2,4,9,12,18], solve([2,4,9,12,18]))
```

[**Live Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zpxe7jm5)

Comment: I don't see why this can be viewed as a knapsack problem. There we want to select m of n items to put in the knapsack but the order of those items selected (e.g., the order in which they are placed in the knapsack) is unimportant. Here ordering is the essence of the problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The way I see it is that it is a flavour of knapsack with an additional constraint of ordering. Hence, sorted the dataset for simplicity and added `if currSum >= ls[currIdx]:` for the constraint check and by passing it on to the next bigger integer.

Comment: Hello all, I apologize for the delayed response. I am grateful to all of you for taking time out of your lives to help me with this problem. @nice_dev , your code satisfies the test conditions from my interview question. The knapsack algorithm is new to me, so I'm trying to learn it now. Once again, thank you to everyone who responded. Cheers!

Comment: @pavanayi420 Great. You can refer the Wikipedia article and lookup for knapsack algorithm online and how it works. I am sure you will be able to grasp quickly.